# Audio Streaming using php

Tags: php, audio-streaming

I need want some reference for a application, in which i will pre-define the time & song and at that time the song starts to play.

For Example, If I want to play a song at 8am. Then that song starts at that time only. Now if user "A" open my webpage at 8am then the song starts to play and other user "B" open webpage at 8:05am then the song must not play from start but both the user should get same audio i.e. user "B" will miss 5 min song.

Need some reference regarding this point.

Comment: PHP alone cannot play audio. You should look into using HTML5 `audio`, and send the data regarding start time from PHP.

Comment: @BenM I might be wrong but I'm fairly sure he knows that. I think the question is how to access an MP3 file on his site and seek to a specific position instead of streaming it from the start.

Comment: The problem that he's going to come across then is connection speed correction, and buffering correction. For example, even if you specify the start time, MP3 still needs to buffer, and the length of time that takes is going to depend on the connection. If it's for pure synchronised listening, this is going to be difficult in PHP alone - there are too many variables to consider.

Comment: Other than PHP what else we need for this? And about the buffering time, then its not a problem about the buffering but it must not be like when every user open the page, the song play from start. I want the song to be in running condition.

Comment: @TusharSharma, How big is this audio file?  If it is small enough, you don't need anything server-side at all.  Some JavaScript will do.

Comment: There is no single file, i want to play sequence of audio files to play as we have in radio. In radio someone speak but we want to pre-define the sequence of many songs and play them as per the sequence continuously.
Secondly I have other issue that when I install Red5 server on my ubuntu PC, it did not allow me to create directory or files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK if you don't have any problem with the buffering and the speed then you can use the free version of [jwplayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/).

Extract the song and its playtime according to the time like its is 8:00pm when user opened the page then extract the song whose playtime and end time lies between the current time(8:00pm).

After that use seek function jwplayer like if the play time of the song is 7:55pm and end time is 8:10pm and the user opened the page on 8:00pm then seek the audio 5 min later with `jwplayer('your_element').seek(5*60);` to seek the video and play the video according to the time